# parsing JSON to display in CollectionViewCell Swift 2

Tags: json, dictionary, swift2

I am only just starting creation of a job app to complement my jobs website but I am having trouble parsing the indeed API which we use to fill up space in any place we don't have jobs.  I can get the content coming through but I can't seem to get it stored into a dictionary and then utilised to create the cells of the Collection View.  My code for the view controller is below and any advice is appreciated as after umpteen tutorials and web searches... I think I broke it completely :

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!


var jobtitle = [[String: String]]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    loadJobs()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(jobtitle.count)
    return jobtitle.count
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    //MyCollectionViewCell

    let myCell: MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    let jobTitleString = self.jobtitle[indexPath.row] as? [String:String]
    let trueJobTitle = jobTitleString!["jobtitle"] // as! String

    myCell.jobTitleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    myCell.jobTitleLabel.text = trueJobTitle

    return myCell

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("User tapped on: \(indexPath.row)")
}



func loadJobs() {

    let startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

    var pageUrl = "http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=8134512135661512&format=json&q=java&l=austin%2C+tx&sort=date&radius=25&st=&jt=&start=&limit=10&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=us&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2"
    let myUrl=NSURL(string: pageUrl)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        // If error display alert message

        if error != nil {
            var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default
                , handler: nil)

            myAlert.addAction(okAction)

            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil )
            return
        }

        do {
            let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as? NSArray

            if let parseJSONArray = jsonArray
            {
                self.jobtitle = parseJSONArray as! [[String:String]]

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.myCollectionView.reloadData()});

            }
        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }

        print(self.jobtitle)

    }

    task.resume()



}
```

}

Comment: Does `print(self.jobtitle)` print anything? Basically the code looks ok, however if the text color and the background color of the cell both are white you won't see anything ;-) . Since `jobtitle` is declared as non-optional delete `as? [String:String]` in cellForItemAtIndexPath` and put the exclamation mark  in the next line **after** the closing bracket.

Comment: print(self.jobtitle) is only in there so I could see if anything was being put in there in xcode, it will be removed in production.  The background colour when running is black which is why I tried putting the text as white.

Answer (score 0):

A quick question: looking at your code, it's not clear to me whether you have set up a UICollectionViewLayout object for your collection view. The layout manager is a crucial element in any implementation of a UICollectionView - when the collection view is first loaded you need to create a layout manager, passing it parameters such as the number of sections/rows and your desired cell width/height etc. The layout manager then builds your layout - only after this has happened will the cellForItemAtIndexPath method be called to actually start populating the collection view. If you don't have a layout manager initialized with a layout the collectionViewController is not going to think there are any cells in the collection view!

Apple offers a built in default layout manager called flow layout, but it is also rather easy to build your own. Essentially (and there are some important things I'm missing out here) you are creating a class that will build an array of frames for your cells, so it's not that complicated.

Anyway, let me know whether you have in fact implemented a layout manager and we can take it from there.